# Positioning divs on top of an image that's utilizing the flex CSS property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For a web application, I'm to position an animated emoji along with some text in a div. These elements are to remain separated in a fully responsive way. Behold:

[image]

I'm using `flex` to accomplish this. That ensures that even if the screen size becomes extremely small, separation is still kept by stacking these one on top of the other.

To accomplish it, the whole outer div is wrapped in:

```
.act{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #E1F5FE;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Next, the animated image inside the div is wrapped in:

```
.anim {
  flex: 1 1;
  min-width: 64px;
  text-align: center;

}

.anim > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

Lastly, the text along with the image is wrapped in:

```
.txt {
  flex: 1 1 180px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

---

Did you notice the tear drops on the emoji? Those are separate from the image, and are to be animated in html5.

I can't figure out how to ensure those tear drops stay precisely around the eyes of the emoji. I have tried using a `z-index` alongwith `position:absolute` (e.g. see the following):

```
    <div class="anim">
          <div class="tear" style="z-index:2;position:absolute;margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 110px;"></div>
          <div class="tear" style="z-index:2;position:absolute;margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 84px;"></div>
          <img src="sad.png">        
    </div>
```

This isn't responsive at all.

Moreover, If I try using`position:relative`, that makes it impossible to overlap the tear shape over the emoji, regardless of what `z-index` I set.

Please help me fix this situation. Ideally, I want to stick to using `flex` because otherwise, it's perfect for my needs.

*Note: Answers to a similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948923/trouble-styling-divs-on-top-of-an-image-css) don't help since I've already included what they're suggesting.*

Comment: Mixing HTML animations and images is always a hard way. Make it responsive is next level harder. It is not impossible but it take more effort than the reward. So if i were you, i'd use `.gif` for the animate emoji. If you still want to make it by css, consider to use only html and css, not image. This [pen](https://codepen.io/franklyg/pen/PwKLPq) is an example

Comment: @HassanBaig Even for the html/css based face, you need the wapper I show in my answer, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ek8xkmqr/

Comment: @LGSon: then isn't the solution/level-of-difficulty to do this essentially the same whether it's an HTML/CSS based face or an image?

Comment: Yes, it is, which I showed with my answer and fiddle, as the key is the wrapper keeping the boundaries for the face and eyes being separate elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish that you need a wrapper around the image and text, that take the size of the image.

Here is a sample code, where I added an extra wrapper, `image`, around the `anim`, and then made the `anim` display as inline block.

Here the `image` wrapper become the flex item instead, and will allow the `anim` to behave and be sized as the image, and create the boundaries you need to be able to place the eyes at a fixed position on top the image.

Stack snippet

```css
.act {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #E1F5FE;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 1;
  min-width: 64px;
  text-align: center;
}

.anim {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.anim>img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.txt {
  flex: 1 1 180px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tear {
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
}
.tear:first-child {
  left: 10px;"
}
```

```html
<div class="act">

  <div class="image">
    <div class="anim">
      <div class="tear"></div>
      <div class="tear"></div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="txt">
    Some text
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you also include a quick conceptual description of how what you've added works?

Comment: @HassanBaig If you add a border to the flex items, you'll see how it looks and when, you'll understand why the extra wrapper is needed ... or you need to fix the width/height of the flex item, which will give the same _fixed_ boundaries the extra wrapper provides.

Comment: Yea dude, I think I'm getting the hang of it. Good tip on using the border to understand how it all comes together :-)

Comment: Follow-up: could you explain why we didn't need to use `z-index` to position the graphics on top of the image?

Comment: @HassanBaig Yes, elements having a position other than `static` will render in its own layer, on top of elements that does have `static`, and in your case the `anim` have position and image does not. If you add `position: relative` to the image, then `z-index` will be needed, or a markup change. FYI, also a flex item has position, even if not set.